# asp.net mvc 5 and oauth2 login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0

I'm working on a asp.net mvc *5* project that will use the meetup.com oauth2 api to login. Unfortunately, I'm having an issue where my webapp successfully redirects to the meetup login page and I can hit "allow", but then it will stop because the AuthenticationHandler detects the properties of the "state" field as null and nothing shows up on the page. I'm using passive AuthenticationMode and afaik meetup.com API doesn't use "state" field, so I'm not sure how to prevent the AuthenticationHandler from returning null and stopping in the middle because it thinks there's an error when there isn't a "state" to begin with. Here is the relevant code:

```
protected override async Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {
        AuthenticationProperties properties = null;

        try
        {
            string code = null;
            string state = null;

            IReadableStringCollection query = Request.Query;
            IList<string> values = query.GetValues("code");
            if (values != null && values.Count == 1)
            {
                code = values[0];
            }
            values = query.GetValues("state");
            if (values != null && values.Count == 1)
            {
                state = values[0];
            }

            properties = Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(state);
            if (properties == null)
            {
                return null; // the error here
            }
```

Comment: Why don't you just modify/override this behavior since your provider doesn't conform to the workflow that is there?

Comment: If I do that, the code will return null elsewhere. I want to know how to make it so that the code does not require the state field. Here is the class in its entirety: http://pastebin.com/Bk7rV4vG

Comment: Yes, you'd have to override behavior wherever it is relying on this state field. You are wanting to use a provider that does not conform with what the built-in authentication logic relies on so you are basically guaranteed to need some custom work.

Answer (score 0):

found a pre-existing open source library that works

https://github.com/KatanaContrib/KatanaContrib.Security.Meetup